# how to create a html page using mustache template?

Tags: mustache

I'm interesting on doing a template using mustache. And I've read about this: http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html.

There is a mustache template and a hash code, my question is:

1. does we write the code on two different files? if yes, on hash code, what extension file we use to save?
2. how to generate the .html file? I mean the output should be on .html file, so how I can produce the output?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this either way keeping everything in one html file is by far the easiest as you don't have use ajax, or require to bring the file in, mustache by itself doesn't have any utilities to read in data from an html file it just takes in a string and spits a rendered version of that string, but if you use [icanhazjs](http://icanhazjs.com/) which uses mustache template syntax it will allow you to create script tags in your html that contain your templates and then you can just call them like this `ich.my_template(obj)` (more info on the website) and it will return a jquery or zepto object by default or alternatively return a string.

Hope this helps.
please feel free to ask me if you need any more help!